# is_dir says dir not exists but it exists

Tags: php, filesystems

I'm not sure what's wrong here. For some reason is_dir function not working properly for me.

```
class A
{
  private $path

  public function setPath($path)
  {
     if(!is_dir(!$path)){
      throw new Exception('Invalid path');
    }

  }
}

$obj = new A;
$obj->setPath('/usr/htdocs/site/');
```

After this line of code the exception Invalid path is thrown. I checked and the /usr/htdocs/site/ path exists. What could be the problem?

Comment: `!$path` - Wut? Remove that `!`.

Comment: remove the "!" in front of $path

Comment: Put a semi-colon at the end of `private $path`, otherwise it will throw `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting ',' or ';' in.....` plus removing the `!` as already stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!$path means if anything in !$path, it will be false. So it will be !is_dir(false).

I think your code will be if (!is_dir($path)) { ... NOT if (!is_dir(!$path)) {

Little Update:

As @NiettheDarkAbsol said, is_dir takes the string (the directory name) as parameter, so the false [which get from !$path ($path should be '/usr/htdocs/site/' in this case, so !$path should be bool false)] will be convert in to string '' (empty).

And the '' is a invalid directory name in most common used file systems. So, the is_dir will can't found the any directory by that invalid name. And because of that, it will return false, which triggered the exception throwing to report you the path is invalid.

Thanks to @NiettheDarkAbsol tell me the rest thing.

Comment: Don't stop there. What does `!is_dir(false)` do? It casts `false` to a string, because it expects said string. So it's doing `!is_dir("")`... So what happens if you have a directory that somehow has no name?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Sorry, my experience is low. I don't truely know what will happen when directory name is empty. I think that will be related to file system, like how the file system locating / seek files in file table.

Comment: Well, the good news is that file and folder names cannot be empty, ever. Unless you're on some kind of exotic custom OS that for some reason allows it.

Answer (score 1):

remove `!` before path variable

try like this:

```
 if(!is_dir($path)){
      throw new Exception('Invalid path');
    }
```